# Format Specifier for Thousands Separator in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have come across this format specifier https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-378-format-specifier-for-thousands-separator- When formatting an integer, include the comma after the width:

```
>>> '{:20,d}'.format(18446744073709551616)
'18,446,744,073,709,551,616'
```

I do not understand why the width is given as 20 here. I tried using the same with 10

```
>>> '{:10,d}'.format(18446744073709551616)
'18,446,744,073,709,551,616'
```

Any explanation would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because it's the number of digits in the number. Which is irrelevant here, because it means something else when formatting.

Comment: Yes, It is confusing.

Comment: I think the `width` specifier is for the *minimum* width required to print all items in the format contents. Thus, the field width will always be at least the size as the data to fill it (i.e. it defaults to the length of contents).

Comment: So, in this case, the minimum width is 10 or 20?

Comment: In this case the minimum width is the width to display all the digits of the 20 digit number ***including*** the 6 separator commas, so `20` + `6`, so minimum width should be `26`. You can tell when you get the minimum width when the next higher width adds padding of white spaces to the left of the output, like this: `'{:27,d}'.format(18446744073709551616)` and shows as: " 18,446,744,073,709,551,616", which has a leading space. But as mentioned above, it's not relevant to formatting, because you can put zero `0` and still get the same output.